# Python Pandas : Group by one column and see the content of all columns?

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, aggregation

I have a dataframe like this:

```
org     group   count
org1      1       2
org2      1       2
org3      2       1
org4      3       3
org5      3       3
org6      3       3
```

and this is what I would like to have , one entry from each unique groups from the 'group' column:

```
org     group   count
org1      1       2
org3      2       1
org4      3       3
```

I am using the following group by command but I still get to see all of the rows:

```
df.groupby('group').head()
```

Does any body know how to get the expected results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call [`first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.first.html#pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.first) on the `groupby` object and optionally call [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html#pandas.DataFrame.reset_index) if you want to return the grouped index back as a column:

```
In [448]:

df.groupby('group').first().reset_index()
Out[448]:
   group   org  count
0      1  org1      2
1      2  org3      1
2      3  org4      3
```

Answer (score 3):

You could `drop_duplicates` on `group`?

```
In [172]: df.drop_duplicates('group')
Out[172]:
    org  group  count
0  org1      1      2
2  org3      2      1
3  org4      3      3
```

Also, `df.drop_duplicates(['group', 'count'])` works in this case.

However, this may not be <strike>the best</strike> a very flexible method. @EdChum's [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29828769/2137255) provides directions for flexibility.

Comment: On a 100,000 row dataset, `.drop_duplicates()` takes 3.7ms as opposed to the 5.3 seconds by `.groupby().first().reset_index()` -- and is a bit clearer as well, I guess.

Comment: I was a bit skeptical about if you would always want to take the first item among duplicates, so I thought `groupby` could be flexible that way. But, with the benchmarks makes sense with current case. Thanks @SAnand